# Applying von Dyck's theorem twice to obtain an isomorphism between two presentations.

Tags: group-theory

Hi: This is from a book in group theory.

[image: Robinson]

$\overline G$ is assumed to have the presentation $\langle \bar x,\bar a \mid {\bar x}^2=1, {\bar x}^{-1}\bar a \bar x= {\bar a}^{-1} \rangle$. And then von Dyck's theorem can be applied to $G$ and $\overline G$. But every relation in $\overline G$ is a relation in $G$. And so by von Dyck's theorem again there is $\phi: \overline G \to G$ in which $\bar x \mapsto x$ and $\bar a \mapsto a$. But then $\theta \phi=\phi \theta=1$ and $\theta$ is an isomorphism. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I quote von Dyck's theorem as given by the author:

[image: Second image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you are doing something wrong? That sounds just fine, its just another way.

Comment: But it is a much easier way! Why does the author take the trouble of proving there is an isomorphism in the way he does?

Comment: Who knows? Ask him.